# Text creating burn-through on gradient while printing in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, print-css

I'm getting the following issue only when choosing a physical printer as my destination from the Chrome (version 64) print prompt. I have a gradient at the top and bottom of the container, with the text being positioned on top.

I tried both setting (and removing) `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` under the @media print CSS and also setting
`background:transparent;` on the elements, neither of which are working.

When I select 'Save as PDF' everything looks fine, it only does this when printing directly to a printer from the print prompt.

How it SHOULD look:

[image]

How it ACTUALLY looks (I know it's darker in print, the real issue is the text background burning through the gradient behind it)

[image]

**Update:** This problem does NOT arise when using Chrome 57 or 60 so it's definitely a problem with newer Chrome versions (63 and 64)